# speeding up as.POSIXct on windows

Tags: r, multicore

I know that you can speed up the `as.POSIXct` function by using `pvec`, from the `multicore` package, but it only works on unix systems such as a mac. Is there a Windows equivalent, that would generate comparable speeds?

Any benchmarking would be interesting to see...

Comment: does `mclapply` from the `parallel` package help?

Comment: not really, if you look on the help page of pvec i.e `?pvec` it says at the bottom that its much slower due to 'each value requiring a separate call to as.POSIXct()'

Comment: You ask for benchmarking. Can you post some reproducible code that illustrates the use case in base R?

Comment: @Andrie, see `help(pvec)` and its examples which has a short study.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that you are confusing two issues.

Nothing here "speeds up `as.POSIXct`", this remains an expensive operation.   What `pvec` does is to run "chunks" of the vector in parallel through the conversion, which minimizes the number of function calls to `as.POSIXct` -- as you quote in your comment above.

`pvec` however relies on forking, and that is something Windows does not offer. There are some fundamental difference between the OSs that matter, this is one of them.